# IP Filter for REST API does not work behind load balancer for Ant Media Server (Tomcat 10)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm using Ant Media Server and I have one load balancer and Ant Media Server instances running behind the load balancer. I want to access to the Ant Media Server REST API by whitelisting my IP address in the IP filter. However it does not work. It works only if the 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR block is whitelisted.

Here are the steps

1. Deploy the server behind load balancer
2. Whitelist your IP in IP filter for Rest API
3. Call any Rest API

Expected behavior
The Rest API call should work as expected

Actual behavior
Rest API call does not work and IP not allowed error comes(403)

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected behavior for public IP addresses due to security reasons. Let me provide you with a comprehensive solution.

Firstly, let's delve into why this is an expected behavior for public IP addresses.

### Why It's a Problem

- When a REST request is sent to the load balancer, the load balancer forwards the request to one of the backend servers.
- The load balancer forwards the request with the `X-Forwarded-For` header, appending the original client's IP address.
- Ant Media Server utilizes the [Remote IP Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve), which accepts local network addresses as trusted (refer to the `internalProxies` section in the link). Accepting addresses outside this range without proper validation could introduce security vulnerabilities.
- It appears the challenge arises when the load balancer and Ant Media Servers are not within the same private network, leading to the issue you're encountering.

### Solution:

The good news is that the Remote IP Valve offers the flexibility to modify `internalProxies` and `trustedProxies`.

> `trustedProxies`: This is a regular expression (using `java.util.regex`) that a proxy's IP address must match to be considered a trusted proxy. Trusted proxies listed in the `remoteIpHeader` will be considered reliable and will appear in the `proxiesHeader` value. If this is not specified, no proxies will be trusted.

I'm leveraging `trustedProxies` for this case. Here's how I approached it:

1. I've set up an instance with a public IP address: `145.239.135.94`. I installed Nginx on it to redirect incoming requests to the OVH36 test server. In this setup, both the Nginx instance and OVH36 test server have public addresses and are located in different regions.
2. I navigated to `/usr/local/antmedia/conf/jee-container.xml` and located the line containing `<bean id="valve.access" class="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />`.
3. I modified the line as shown below, paying special attention to the inclusion of the load balancer's address in `trustedProxies`:

```xml
<bean id="valve.access" class="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve">
  <property name="trustedProxies" value="145.239.135.94"/>
</bean>
```

4. Then, I restarted the Ant Media Server:

```shell
sudo service antmedia restart
```

5. Subsequently, I added my public address to the REST IP Filter:
   [image]
6. After that, I made a request to the load balancer using curl in my local terminal:

```bash
curl http://145.239.135.94:5080/WebRTCAppEE/rest/v2/broadcasts/count
```

Result:

```
{"number":1}
```

The server returned the expected result, indicating a successful configuration.

I hope this solution is effective for your setup as well. Please try it out and let me know how it goes. Should you have any questions or require further assistance, feel free to reach out.

[Documentation](https://antmedia.io/docs)

Best regards,
Oguz